# Implicit function theorem checking

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Use IFT to

1)show F(x,y) = y^2+2xy+x-1=0 can be solved for y in terms of x near all point $(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0\neq -x_0$

2) Check the result directly

3) Determine if the equation F(x,y)=0 is locally solvable near any point $(x_0,-x_0)$

My attempt:

1) y can be solved in terms of x since  $\dfrac {\partial F}{\partial y}=2y+2x\neq 0$. Hence if $y_0=-x_0$,

2) Check directly: Suppose $y_0=-x_0$ then $F(x_0,y_0)=-x_0^2+x_0-1$. Am I right?

2) Near $(x_0,-x_0)$, F(x_0,-x_0) = x_0^2-x_0+1 =0$ has no solution. Hence is not solvable. But my professor commented: "Lucky you". So that I knew my argument is not correct. I would like to make it clear. Someone helps me, please

Comment: In (2) it is not right. You need to check that the result from (1) directly. That is, suppose $y_0\neq x_0$ and solve the equation $y^2+2xy+x-1=0$ for $y$ in terms of $x$ near the point $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that from item $1$ you know you can solve  $F(x,y) = y^2+2xy+x-1=0$ for $y$ as a function of $x$ in a neighborhood of any point $(x,y)$ s.t. $y\neq -x$. Your calculation in $2$ shows that if $y_0=−x_0$ then $F(x_0,y_0)=−x^2_0+x_0−1$. But this quadratic polynomial has no real roots. So $F(x_0,y_0)\neq 0$, and by continuity there is a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $F(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in U$.

That means that no point of the form $(x_0,-x_0)$ is a solution to the equation $F(x,y)=0$, so you can not solve for $y$ in function of $x$ near such point.

Answer (score 2):

To solve item $(2)$ rewrite $y^2+2xy+x−1=0$ as $(y+x)^2-x^2+x-1=0$, or $(y+x)^2=x^2-x+1$. Then solve for $y$ as a function of $x$

Comment: I did and got y as what @Frieder did below. I meant I got $y=-x\pm \sqrt {x^2-x+1}$ But my prof commented: "This is not function of x" . I do not know how to fix.

Comment: Or I have to separate them as 2 functions like what Frieder did? since I combine them in $y = -x \color{red}{\pm}\sqrt{x^2-x+1}$ which is not correct in notation? how about the last argument?

Comment: That is correct. The function you need to use depends on the initial point you chose. I mean, suppose $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point such that $F(x_0,y_0)= 0$ and $y_0>-x_0$, so for (x,y) next to $(x_0,y_0)$ you still have $y>-x$. When you take square root in the equation you get $|(y+x)|=\sqrt{(x^2-x+1)}$ since we are in the case $y>-x$ we have $y+x=|y+x|=\sqrt{(x^2-x+1)}$ so that $y=-x +\sqrt{(x^2-x+1)}$. On the other hand if $F(x_0,y_0)= 0$ and $y_0<-x_0$, then $|y+x|=-x-y$ and you will have to use the other solution, with minus before the square root.